# VISBRAIN in IronPython 2.7.8

Tags: c#, import, ironpython, importerror

I am using Window 7, 64 bit.

using Anaconda3.
Anaconda3 is in my D.

I am running a C# application in Visual Studio 2017 Community, trying to run Visbrain from ironpython.

IronPython that I am using is IronPython version 2.7.8.

I had included IronPython.Modules.dll, IronPython.dll, Microsoft.Scripting.dll, Microsoft.Dynamic.dll.

my .net framework is 4.0.

below is my code:

```
// create python engine
var myPythonEngine = Python.CreateEngine();

// create search path
var searchPaths = myPythonEngine.GetSearchPaths();

searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Anaconda3\envs\myenv3604\Lib"); // using anaconda 3
//searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Python 35\Lib"); // python standard library

searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Anaconda3\envs\myenv3604\lib\site-packages"); // using anaconda 3
//searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Python 35\lib\site-packages"); // visbrain inside here

// set search path
myPythonEngine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);

// create scope to execute python code and get backs results from python code
var myScope = myPythonEngine.CreateScope();

// create the source
var mySource = myPythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"test12345.py");

// execute the scope
mySource.Execute(myScope);
```

but after I run my code, it pops out.

```
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named visbrain'
```

**tried solution:**

1) [IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module named os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737763/ironpython-runtime-exceptions-importexception-no-module-named-os)

I added the lib to my search path, but still no luck

**Solution for 1) :**

according to [Why can't I import my C# type into IronPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765919/why-cant-i-import-my-c-sharp-type-into-ironpython)

added

```
searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Python35\DLLs");
searchPaths.Add(@"D:\Python35\lib\site-packages");
```

===

but after I run again, it pops out this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException' in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
unexpected token 'exc_info'
```

stack trace is below:

```
Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=unexpected token 'exc_info'
  Source=IronPython
  StackTrace:
   at IronPython.Runtime.ThrowingErrorSink.Add(SourceUnit sourceUnit, String message, SourceSpan span, Int32 errorCode, Severity severity)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(Int32 start, Int32 end, String message, Int32 errorCode)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(Token t, IndexSpan span, Int32 errorCode, Boolean allowIncomplete)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseVarArgsList(TokenKind terminator)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFuncDef()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseClassOrFuncBody()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseClassDef()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFileWorker(Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFile(Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.ParseAndBindAst(CompilerContext context)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompilePythonCode(SourceUnit sourceUnit, CompilerOptions options, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run8[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`5.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run8[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`5.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`5.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at WindowsFormsAppJTTH.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\JamesTan\source\repos\WindowsFormsAppJTTH\WindowsFormsAppJTTH\Form1.cs:line 170
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at WindowsFormsAppJTTH.Program.Main() in C:\Users\JamesTan\source\repos\WindowsFormsAppJTTH\WindowsFormsAppJTTH\Program.cs:line 19
```

Would like to know is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I read up all the documentation and this is what i found.

According to the documentation of Visbrain (http://visbrain.org/), Visbrain is Python 3 package.

According to the developers of Iron Python, they are currently working on Iron Python 2, which cannot support Python 3 package.

So, this error might be solved when Iron Python 3 is implemented.